# Amazon s3 upload is a small grey square?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I"m trying to upload to Amazon S3 but all I get is a small grey square when viewing the item in the browser?

[image]

I am using express/multer and serverless framework

```
router.post(
  "/images",
  upload.single("image"),
  async (req: ImageReq, res, next) => {
    const { file } = req;

    const fileName = path.parse(file.originalname).name; //=> "hello"
    const fileType = path.parse(file.originalname).ext; //=> ".html"

    const newFileName = slugify(`${fileName}${fileType}`);

    console.log(newFileName);

    s3.upload(
      {
        Bucket: BUCKET,
        Key: newFileName,
        Body: file.buffer,
        ACL: "public-read",
        ContentType: mime.lookup(file.originalname),
      },
      (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("DATA", data);
        return res.send({ ok: true });
      }
    );
```

This will log

```
{
  ETag: '"<redacted>"',
  Location: 'https://<redacted>.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/jpg.jpeg',
  key: 'jpg.jpeg',
  Key: 'jpg.jpeg',
  Bucket: '<redacted>'
}
```

The file obj received in the request is:

```
{
  fieldname: 'image',
  originalname: 'jpg.jpeg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  buffer: <Buffer c3 bf c3 98 c3 bf c3 a0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 60 00 60 00 00 c3 bf c3 a1 00 c2 b7 45 78 69 66 00 00 4d 4d 00 2a 00 00 00 08 00 06 01 1a 00 ... 461934 more bytes>,
  size: 461984
}
```

This happened on the latest @aws-sdk/client-s3 package too and I can't seem to get images to upload and display correctly

Answer (score 2):

After doing some digging on Stackoverflow and Github, I found an issue relating to [serverless-offline and image uploads](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/issues/464).

It isn't a complete fix as I still cannot get images to upload locally using `serverless-offline`, but I had to add the following to my `serverless.yml`

I could then only get images uploaded when I deployed to aws.

```
apiGateway:
  binaryMediaTypes:
    - "*/*"
```